# Cannot compile Laravel assets on new Homestead install

Tags: laravel, homestead, laravel-jetstream

UPDATE 3 (LATEST)

Per suggestion below (from justanothereddie), configuring the drive as NFS fixed the problem.  I am not sure why though, so will leave the question open for a few more days.

UPDATE 2

Just purchased a new MacBook Pro, but the problem remains.  I can run an `npm install`, provided the folder is not shared with the host.  If it is shared with the host, it fails.

UPDATE 1

I have discovered that I can compile the Laravel assets if the drive I am working in is not shared with the host.  I am running the distro's VirtualBox package, which is 6.1.10.  The latest release is 6.1.12, so perhaps that will fix it.

EDIT:

Originally I thought this problem was related to Laravel Jetstream, but I now see that it is related to Laravel more broadly.  I have done a `vagrant destroy` to remove the machine, and removed my Homestead directory, and reinstalled Homestead from scratch.

When I do a `laravel new my_project` is installs fine, but as soon as I issue `npm install` it fails with the same error message as below.  I can not understand why no one else is reporting this.  This is a very simple process which I have completed successfully about 100 times in the past, and the only thing I have not tried is new hardware or VirtualBox install.

ORIGINAL POST:

Did a `vagrant destroy` a few days ago and installed the new Homestead on my Ubuntu host (20.04.1). Trying to install Jetstream for the first time, the inertia stack, with `--teams`. Tried both the `vagrant new` method, and the composer method. Failed both times with the following error.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/code/ftmv2/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/yargs-parser/package.json.1863223755
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/code/my_test/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/yargs-parser/package.json.1863223755'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Removed the `node_modules` directory and retried `npm_install`, but outcome is the same.

- Jetstream Version: ^1.2
- Jetstream Stack: Inertia
- Laravel Version: ^8.0
- PHP Version: ^7.3
- Laravel Installer Version: 4.0.3
- NPM version: 6.14.8

Comment: Does this helps you https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/992#issuecomment-289935776 ?

Comment: Thanks Clement, things are working OK now (see NFS workaround above).  I may look further at this suggestion if required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've suffered with this issue for a long time and it seems that the problem is using *npm install* as a vagrant user inside a *laravel/homestead box* so the main issue is one of permissions on a synced folder which is the main task of Homestead.yaml.

Referenced in: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html

There's two solutions for this problem:

One will enable you to work from homestead normally, and the other is just like a patch of sorts.

Insert the next line just below your folder mapping on Homestead.yaml

```
type: "nfs"
```

Documentation of that here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead

Next option is just working from your system, that has all permissions since it "owns" the folder in wich you are working.

**Instead of executing npm install inside vagrant go to the folder in your system (your computer) and use the command from there.**

If you need to clean install your project use:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
```

Answer (score 5):

Had the exact same issue on my MacBook Pro and added type: "nfs" to "folders" in my Homestead.yaml. Did a vagrant reload --provision and now npm will install and compile

Comment: Wow, thanks.  That worked.  I am not sure why, so will leave the question open for a few days more.